# Image Gallery Horizontal Scrolling With Divs

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to create an Image Gallery where the user can scroll through the images for each page horizontally (left-right swiping as this is meant for mobile phones and tablets). I can not figure out where I went wrong, anyone have any idea?

My code is found at 
http://jsfiddle.net/8tDYk/

CSS:

```
.media{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 288px; 
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -ms-overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.image{
    float: left;
    height: 240px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 3.2%;
    text-align:center;
    border: 7px solid white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="media">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""></a>
     </div>
    <div class="image">
        <a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""></a>
     </div>
    <div class="image">
        <a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""></a>
     </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an element has `float:left;`, it will position itself to the right of the previous element (if there is space)
Otherwise, the element will position itself on the line beneath it.

You can see this when you set `overflow-y: visible;` on `.media`

One way of preventing this from happening, is to make an extra inner div, in which you set the width explicitely (Javascript is a big help there) like this:

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""></a>
     </div>
     <div class="image">
        <a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
          <a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""></a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could then use jquery to set a width for imageContainer like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var imageWidth = 240;
   $(document.ready()
   {
     $(".imageContainer").width($(".image").length*imageWidth);
   });
</script>
```

::UPDATE::

Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7SLN7/2/)

Comment: Additionally, you could use some javascript to get the scrolling to work more like you would expect from swipe gestures

Comment: And the javascript here will add extra width per image? Did I understand that right? :P

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8tDYk/ When I click the mouse-scroll wheel I can scroll down and still find the pictures lined up underneath rather than to the right. Do I need some more parameters in the imageContainer part of the CSS perhaps?

Comment: I forgot to take into account that the images had a border and margin.
I removed them in this working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/7SLN7/2/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your .media element,it is set to 100% so how the overflow-x will work.Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MohammadHamza/jXkht/).
According to this the content you want to scroll is in another div having different style.
The Markup is

```
    <div class='scroll'>
<div class="media">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""/></a>
     </div>
    <div class="image">
        <a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""/></a>
     </div>
    <div class="image">
        <a href="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGr4F-VQME__rGsSQitz9PkWGJ7C1XbUlhkleUw-5JVyYImWJ6hg" height="250px" style="max-width: 100%;" alt=""/></a>
     </div>    
    </div></div>
```

The CSS is

```
.media
{
width: 100%; 
height: 288px; 
float: left;
display: inline-block;
overflow-x: auto;
-ms-overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
-ms-overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}

    .image
    {
    float: left;
    height: 240px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 3.2%;
    text-align:center;
    border: 7px solid white;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tDYk/2/)

in your .image class set width in pixels as

```
.image
{
   width: 400px;
   ..... 
}
```

Comment: But I don't know how many images there will be, could be 1 and it could be 104. Is there no way to automatically adjust this?